# Пытаюсь написать дождь на java - AWT, Swing

Tags: java, swing, awt

Я пытаюсь написать дождь на java, но пока никак не могу заставить дождинку двигаться:

```java
package com.company;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyWindow myWindow = new MyWindow();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

class MyWindow extends JFrame {
    public MyWindow() {
        setTitle("My Window");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(300, 300, 500, 400);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        RainField RF = new RainField();
        add(RF, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setResizable(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class RainField extends JPanel {
    public int i = 0;
    protected float x = getWidth() / 2, y = 0, yspeed = 1;

    public RainField() {
        for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            y += 10;
            // repaint();
        }
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        setBackground(Color.orange);
        int x = getWidth() / 2;
        int y = 99;
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawLine(x, y, x, y + 10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Main** - *без изменений*

```java
package com.company;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyWindow myWindow = new MyWindow();
    }
}
```

Далее много ошибок у вас.

**MyWindow**

```java
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class MyWindow extends JFrame {
    public MyWindow() {
        setTitle("My Window");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(300, 300, 500, 400);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        RainField RF = new RainField();

        add(RF, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // ширина у JPanel появляется после
        // того, как он становится частью JFrame
        RF.setX(getWidth() / 2);

        setResizable(true);
        setVisible(true);

        // Создаем поток, в котором будем
        // перерисовывать JFrame
        Thread thread = new Thread(RF);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

**RainField**

```java
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

// Добавляем интерфейс Runnable
public class RainField extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    public int i = 0;
    protected int x, y;

    // Добавляем сеттер для (Х)
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    // Определяем функцию для потока
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            // Указываем задержку перед изменением
            // координаты (Х),
            // чтобы глаз что-то заметить успел
            try {
                Thread.sleep(60);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            y += 10;

            if (y > getHeight()) {
                y = 0;
            }
            // Обновляем отображение
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // Эту строчку обязательно надо добавить
        // чтобы лишних глюков не было
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Ну и сама перерисовка
        setBackground(Color.orange);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawLine(x, y, x, y + 10);
    }
}
```